# Hide toggle Apple bug reporter?

Tags: development

While checking out my bugs in Radar on my iPhone, I discovered a "hide" toggle that appears when you hit the arrow at the bottom right if the screen. It is set to hide by default - what is it? How should it be set?

Answer (score 1):

This is just a guess but perhaps it is to allow you to start documenting a bug but only make it visible when you have completed documenting it.

All Apple seemed to say about it is: "**Hidden:** these reports are hidden from view".

https://developer.apple.com/bug-reporting/using-bug-reporter/